# Convert guint8 to uint32_t in C/glib

Tags: c, glibc, glib

I cant find a way to convert guint8 to uint32_t in C

I tried:

```
uint32_t *uint32_value = (uint32_t *)guint8_value;
```

but it says:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   uint32_t *uint32_value = (uint32_t *)guint8_value
                            ^
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   uint32_t *uint32_value = (uint32_t *)guint8_value
                          ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't casting from `guint8` to `uint32_t`.

You are casting from an integer (`guint8`) to a pointer to an integer (`uint32_t*`)

The correct code is very simple:

```
uint32_t uint32_value = guint8_value;
```